# Array of shared pointers that point to struct elements, what kind of a syntax?

Tags: arrays, c++11, struct, smart-pointers

I need an array a size of n that has shared pointers and each of those point to one struct element. What is the syntax?

Is it just

```
shared_ptr<Struct_name> array(new Struct_name(n));
```

or something else?

Should I use C++ array (#include array) instead of C array?

And what about releasing the memory when there is no need for the array anymore? Do smart pointers handle it for arrays also or do I have to delete every array element by

```
delete array[i]
```

Comment: Do you want the objects to share a lifetime, or not?  Is the size of the array determined at compile time, or run time?  Who owns a pointer to the array (as opposed to elements), and what can they do to it?  How do clients request an element of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a relatively uncomplicated version of what you're asking for:

```
struct S {};
std::array<std::shared_ptr<S>, N> arr;
std::generate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), []() { return std::make_shared<S>(); });
```

If `N` isn't constant, then I'd probably just recommend using a `std::vector<T>`.

```
struct S {};
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<S>> vec(n);
std::generate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), []() { return std::make_shared<S>(); });
```

Finally, the entire point behind a smart pointer is to allow the object to automatically delete the backing memory. So in general, you don't need to explicitly delete memory that is managed by a smart pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why is `std::generate` is needed? Could it be replaced by for example `arr = std::make_shared<S>(N)` ?

Comment: @Masza: No, it couldn't. The main reason is that the line you suggest wouldn't compile. `std::make_shared<S>` has the type `shared_ptr<S>`, while `arr` has the type `std::array<shared_ptr<S>, N>`.

Comment: Ok. What kind values do the array elements have after that? Are the `nullptr` or something else?

Comment: @Masza: Before the call to `std::generate` all of the elements of `arr` contain valid `shared_ptr` that point to `nullptr`. After the call to `generate` they each point to a unique piece of valid memory.

Comment: @Masza: Basically, before the call to `generate`, we've used the default constructor on each of the shared_ptrs. The default constructor says that the managed pointer initially points to `nullptr`. The lambda that we use with `std::generate` will then give a unique shared_ptr to each entry in the array.

Comment: So, is the `std::generate` actually necessary if those `shared_ptr`:s already point to `nullptr`:s? I mean, when I insert something into the array I'll still have to reserve memory for the struct by `new S`. Or is the whole array just one `shared_ptr` before the `std::generate`?

Comment: @Masza: I think you should try out the code that I've shown. You can query the current managed pointer by printing (for example) `arr[4].get()`.

Comment: Ok, I tried. For example `arr[i] = std::make_shared<S>()` without `std::generate` seems to work also. But is the memory usage still the same w/wo `std::generate`when the array doesn't have any real (i.e. all struct variables have some values) elements?

Comment: The call to std::generate is more or less identical to: `for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) arr[i] = std::make_shared<S>();`

Comment: It's also more or less identical to: `for (int i=0; i<arr.size(); ++i) arr[i] = std::shared_ptr<S>(new S);` _There is a reason that we use `make_shared` over this code. Don't worry about it for now. It has to do with exceptions begin thrown and a small performance improvement._

Comment: I think I'll need `nullptr` in my code to tell if the `arr[i]` is pointing to an element so I think I'll just use `arr[i] = std::make_shared<S>()` Thanks a lot for the help!